# Taxes for W2 + 1099

Tags: united-states, income-tax

I have a full time job as a normal employee (W2) which pays $127k / year. Having always been a W2, I know the familiar taxes on the check:

- Federal Income Tax
- State Income Tax (CA)
- SSI
- Medicare

I know that the total for SSI + Medicare is 15.3%, split evenly between employer and employee. I know there's formulas and stuff that determine FIT and SIT amounts (I think CA is very similar to the federal method, just on a smaller scale).

However, I now also have a 1099 situation, where it's $45k / year. I know I have to do the taxes myself on that, but everywhere I've read, it only ever mentions the 15.3% FICA that I have to pay all of myself.

But I can't find anything that mentions FIT or SIT. I don't want to naively think "Great, I don't have to pay federal or state income taxes!" There's no way you simply get away with that. I want to set aside the money for taxes each time I get paid so that when it comes to tax time next year, I won't have any big surprises and will basically be squared away. But I can't find how I'm supposed to calculate federal and state taxes (not the flat 15.3% for FICA). I think I also read something about once your total income goes over $150k combined W2 and 1099, the tax situation changes a bit too, so that complicates things further.

I just want to have an accurate figure of what I need to take out each time I get a check from the 1099 job, other than the 15.3% FICA figure, so that I don't still owe thousands to the IRS because I wasn't setting the right amount aside all year.

Comment: You should consult the IRS Small Business and Self-Employed Tax Center
[https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed]

Comment: This is way too wide. You're basically asking to explain to you how self-employment taxes and estimated tax payments work. Please go through the link in the previous comment and come back with a bit more focus.

Comment: If you have both payroll (W2) and 'gig' (1099) income, instead of making actual estimated payments you can use W4 to request extra payroll withholding. 'FICA' (actually SECA) is 15.3% on _92.35% of_ 1099-NEC income _less deductible expenses_ until it plus W2 income reaches the Social Security 'cap' which changes each year but for 2023 is $160,200; for 2022 it was $147,000 which may be the 'something' you read. Additional Medicare Tax also kicks in for earned income over $250k MFJ $125k MFS $200k otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to have an accurate figure of what I need to take out each
> time I get a check from the 1099 job, other than the 15.3% FICA
> figure, so that I don't still owe thousands to the IRS because I
> wasn't setting the right amount aside all year.

With significant 1099 income in addition to your W-2 income you are now responsible for setting aside money and sending in money quarterly to the IRS.

Ignoring for a moment the FICA calculation, if you were to have 45K in 1099 income and you are in the 22% tax bracket then that gig income tax would require $9,900 in additional Federal income tax being sent in your quarterly payments. That amount is hard to cover just by making w-4 adjustments with changes to your w-4.

For federal responsibilities start with the [Small Business and Self-Employed Tax Center](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed).  You will need to search the state tax website for their forms and requirements.

one other place to start is under a program run by the US Small Business Administration (a part of the federal government):[Small Business Development Centers (SBDC)](https://www.sba.gov/local-assistance/resource-partners/small-business-development-centers-sbdc).  These centers can help small businesses get started. They are also experts on the local tax issues.